# No output from cgitb running Python CGI on Mongoose web server

Tags: python, mongoose, cgi

I am using Python through CGI on the Mongoose web server (v5.6) under Windows. I am able to get a CGI script to execute, but whenever there is an error I just get a blank page in the browser. I have tried forcing an error with the simple script below, but with or without cgitb enabled I don't get any output. How can I get the expected traceback information on error?

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python 2.7.10\python.exe

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"
#Script works as expected without the unmatched quote below.
print "
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cgitb is only possible when you have a valid python script. When you run your script in a regular python interpreter your script will not execute at all an say something like:

```
File "./test.py", line 8
    print "
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

If your python script wont execute there is no chance for cgitb to put the error properly into the outputfile.